# how to put non similar strings of a row in one element and count them

Tags: r, string

I have a data like this with many blank spaces

```
df<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"P42356", "Q9NZT1"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "P63241,Q6IS14"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "P42356,Q8N8J0,A4QPH2", 
    "Q13835"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("", "P63241"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "P63241", "Q13835"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))


> df
#      V1            V2                   V3     V4     V5
#1 Q9NZT1                             Q13835        Q13835
#2                                                        
#3 P42356               P42356,Q8N8J0,A4QPH2              
#4             P63241,Q6IS14                   P63241   P63241
```

I want to add two columns in this **df** lets say V6 and V7
the first one, keep only one string among all similar strings in one row and count all string in each row

example output is like this

```
  V6                       V7
Q9NZT1,Q13835              2
      -                    0
P42356,Q8N8J0,A4QPH2       3
P63241,Q6IS14              2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`

```
do.call(rbind,apply(df, 1, function(x) {
     v1 <- unique(unlist(strsplit(unique(x), ',')))
      data.frame(V6=toString(v1),V7=length(v1))}))
#                       V6 V7
# 1         Q9NZT1, Q13835  2
# 2                         0
# 3 P42356, Q8N8J0, A4QPH2  3
# 4         P63241, Q6IS14  2
```

Comment: is it also possible to count all string similar and not similar per each row ?

Comment: I did it like this, don't worry do.call(rbind,apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  v1 <- unlist(strsplit((x), ','))
  data.frame(V6=toString(v1),V7=length(v1))}))

Comment: yes, I did! thanks for a clear solution which helped me to understand it